# How to create a directory when building with waf

Tags: waf

As part of my build, I need to create a directory.  With waf, I can, for example, create symlinks with `Build.BuildContext.symlink_as`. But I can not find something like `mkdir`.  What is the best way to create an empty directory (ideally at install time).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a `mkdir()` method in the `Node` object. So you can do something like:

```
def build(bld):

    # create foo directory in the build directory 

    bld.path.get_bld().make_node("foo").mkdir()
```

WAF usually create directories whenever needed.

If you want to create a directory outside of the build tree, when installing, you can use bare python, like:

```
import os

def build(bld):

    if bld.cmd == "install":

        d = os.path.join(bld.options.destdir, "what/ever/you/want")
        if not os.path.exists(d):
            os.makedirs(d)
```

Note that `bld.options.destdir` can be modified by the `--destdir` option :)

Comment: Thanks, but I need to create a directory in the install directory.

Comment: @Damascus Steel: ok, I've edited consequently. Let me know if it is ok.